C# Getting the Id value in treeView1
In the following lines of code, I am listing the information in the database to the TreeView in the Documents table. I am adding it in 3 breakdowns. At the top I list the CompanyCode, below I list the data according to the Categories. When listing, I list only the FileAdi column. I assigned the Id value as a tag, but it shows the FileAdi value in the double click event. I want it to show the Id value.
   private void LoadTree() 

 { 

 firmaKodu = GlobalSettings.Instance.FirmaKodu;
       IQueryable<Dokuman> query = dbContext.Dokumanlar;

   if (firmaKodu != 1)
   {
       query = query.Where(d => d.FirmaKodu == firmaKodu);
   }

   var groupedData = query
       .GroupBy(d => new { d.FirmaKodu, d.FirmaAdi })
       .Select(firmGroup => new
       {
           FirmaKodu = firmGroup.Key.FirmaKodu,
           FirmaAdi = firmGroup.Key.FirmaAdi,
           Categories = firmGroup.GroupBy(d => d.Kategori)
                                 .Select(categoryGroup => new
                                 {
                                     Kategori = categoryGroup.Key,
                                     Documents = categoryGroup.Select(d => new { d.Id, d.DokumanAdi, d.DokumanNo }).ToList()
                                 }).ToList()
       }).ToList();

   treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

   foreach (var firm in groupedData)
   {
       var firmNode = new TreeNode($"{firm.FirmaKodu} - {firm.FirmaAdi}")
       {
           ImageIndex = 0,
           SelectedImageIndex = 0
       };

       foreach (var category in firm.Categories)
       {
           var categoryNode = new TreeNode(category.Kategori)
           {
               ImageIndex = 1,
               SelectedImageIndex = 1
           };

           foreach (var document in category.Documents)
           {
               var documentNode = new TreeNode(document.DokumanNo + " " + document.DokumanAdi)
               {
                   ImageIndex = 2,
                   SelectedImageIndex = 2,
                   Tag = document.Id
               };
               categoryNode.Nodes.Add(documentNode);
           }

           firmNode.Nodes.Add(categoryNode);
       }

       treeView1.Nodes.Add(firmNode);


    }
   }

 private void treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
 {
     // Tag değerini kontrol et ve yazdır
     var tagValue = e.Node.Tag;
     MessageBox.Show($"Tag değeri: {tagValue}");          
 }

}


I have removed the  tag since this isn't really related to the SQL language. Perhaps you want do add  tag instead?

This is a very bad code. It queries the database repeatedly in a loop. Use GroupBy instead of Distinct. Then you will get two levels at once. Finally you can apply another GroupBy to the resulting 2nd level to get the 3rd level without re-querying the database. I see no way the messagebox could display FileAdi. The Tag doesn't change magically from dosya.Id to FileAdi.

Your edited code is much better now. DevExpress has a TreeList, not a TreeView. You seem to be using a System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.

Can you share a minimal reproducible example without personal privacy through GitHub? @Burhan Kes.
